# How to disable i18next multiple plurals

Tags: i18next

I'm building an app that `Hebrew` is the main language.

I18next is defined for `Hebrew` to use [multiple plurals](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/plurals#languages-with-multiple-plurals), but, because I'm using numbers these variations are not relevant.

It forces me to specify all variants.

```
{
  ...
    "BEDROOM": "חדר שינה אחד",
    "BEDROOM_1": "$t(BEDROOM_plural)",
    "BEDROOM_2": "$t(BEDROOM_plural)",
    "BEDROOM_3": "$t(BEDROOM_plural)",
    "BEDROOM_plural": "{{count}} חדרי שינה",
  ...
}
```

The lib do have [`simplifyPluralSuffix`](https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options#translation-defaults), but it is exactly the opposite of what I need.

There is any config that will fallback to `_plural` if there is no key for any special variants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jamuhl suggested in [here](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/1374#issuecomment-568532552), It is possible to override plural rules

```js
i18next.services.pluralResolver.addRule('he', {
  numbers: [1, 2, 20, 21],
  plurals: function(n) {
    return Number(n != 1);
  },
});
```

https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/master/src/PluralResolver.js#L90